# Using a public variable to store a path, and using it in another module

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I have a workbook with different modules, each with a different purpose.

**What the code does:** 
The **first module** opens a FileDialog box that requires the user to select the path where the source files (.csv) are, then it searches and pastes the names of each source file into the main workbook.

The **second module** reads the file names and using the "pathS" variable; from the first module, gets the information from the source workbooks.

The **third module** cleans all the information and outputs it to new workbooks.

**What I already tried:** The variable pathS is defined in the first module as the location of the source files, and it is then used in module 2 to locate the files (for info extraction). I declared it as public in module 1, outside the sub.

**The Problem:** When I run the module 2, it cannot find the source files.

**Question:** Is there anything wrong with the way I am using the variable?

**Relevant Code:**

**Module 1:**

```
Option Explicit

Global pathS As String

Sub Counter()

Dim count As Integer, i As Long, var As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim w As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim FileTypeUserForm As UserForm
Dim x As String
Dim varResult As Variant
Dim OutPath As String, OutPathS As String, wPos As Long

Set w = ThisWorkbook

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 'source input by user

        varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Comma Separated Values Files" & "(*.csv), *.csv", Title:="OutPath", InitialFileName:="D:StartingPath")

        If varResult <> False Then
            OutPath = varResult
            w.Worksheets("FILES").Cells(1, 4) = varResult

        Else

            Exit Sub

        End If


wPos = InStr(OutPath, "\StartingPath")
OutPathS = Mid(OutPath, 1, wPos - 1)

pathS = OutPathS & "\*.*"

Filename = Dir(pathS)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Range("A:A").ClearContents


x = GetValue
If x = "EndProcess" Then Exit Sub


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES")
i = 0
Do While Filename <> ""
    var = InStr(Filename, x)

    If var <> 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Filename
        Filename = Dir()

    Else: Filename = Dir()
    End If

Loop

Range("A2:A" & i).Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo 'this will sort the names directly in the "FILES" sheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ws.Cells(1, 2) = i

MsgBox i & " : files found in folder"
End Sub
```

**Module 2 (only until the error line):**

```
Sub Gatherer()
Dim w As Workbook
Dim w2 As Workbook
Dim start1 As Long, end1 As Long, end2 As Long, i As Long, lRow As Long, lColumn As Long, t As Long, k As Long, position As Long, g As Long, C As Long
Dim WBArray() As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

Set w = ThisWorkbook

'clean all worksheets in the main file (except FILES), and set date format
For Each ws In w.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "FILES" Then
        ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
        ws.Range("D1", "XFD1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    End If
Next ws

'Optimize Macro Speed Start
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  

'opens the first workbook file
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(1, 2).Value + 1 'has to be +1, otherwise the last source file is not accounted for

'error is in this next line, it does not find the file
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=pathS & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(i, 1).Value
```

Comment: You have 2 options: **Option 1:** (safer but not best as CPU and memory consuming). Add another module, dedicated only for `Global` vairables, and inside it declare `Option Explicit` , and underneath `Global pathS As String`, this will allow all modules to recognize this variable. However, if you don't run `Sub`Counter` first, you will get an error.  **Option 2:** change to `Public pathS As String`.

Comment: @ShaiRado Explicitly speaking, what is the practical difference between using public and global in this case?

Comment: @ShaiRado Option 1 doesn't make sense because he already declared the variable as global in module 1. @DGMS89 instead of `Workbooks.Open Filename:=pathS & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(i, 1).Value` use `msgbox pathS & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(i, 1).Value` to see what the path looks like. I guess there is a missing backslash or something.

Comment: @Peh That is what i am currently trying to do, but there is this strange behavior: when I open the workbook and run the macros for the first time, module 2 is giving me the error (not finding the file). If I end the break mode and run it again, it works normally. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You can try to monitor the variable `pathS` to see whats happening on the first run and go through it step by step. Hard to say whats wrong there. Make sure `pathS` is not empty on the first run.

Comment: @Peh Found it. For some reason, on the first run, it is putting a "." before the file name, which does not happen on the subsequent runs. Quite a peculiar behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefix the module name to the variable to be sure about which varaiable you are trying to access and also whether you have access to it.

Example works fine:

### Module1

```
Option Explicit

Public foo As String

Sub Test1()

    Module1.foo = "bar"
    Module2.Test2

End Sub
```

### Module2

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test2()

    MsgBox Module1.foo

End Sub
```